# Not able to upload file on Microsoft azure node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to upload file from client which is in react to node server which is hosted on Azure web app

Application logs on azure show me this error "This error means that the request sent to the Web server contained an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the configured module handler for the request"

---

### web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <webSocket enabled="false" />
      <handlers>
         <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
         <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <!-- Don't interfere with requests for logs -->
            <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$" />
            </rule>
            <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
            <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
            </rule>
            <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
            <rule name="StaticContent">
               <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
            <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
               <conditions>
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options -->
      <!--<iisnode
          node_env="%node_env%"
          nodeProcessCommandLine="&amp;quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&amp;quot;"
          nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
          maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
          maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="3"
          namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="2000"
          maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
          maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
          asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
          initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
          maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
          watchedFiles="*.js"
          uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"
          gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
          loggingEnabled="true"
          logDirectoryNameSuffix="logs"
          debuggingEnabled="true"
          debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
          debuggerPathSegment="debug"
          maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
          appendToExistingLog="false"
          logFileFlushInterval="5000"
          devErrorsEnabled="true"
          flushResponse="false"
          enableXFF="false"
          promoteServerVars=""
         />-->
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### Updated : Code

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer    =    require('multer');
var router = express.Router();
var logwrite = require('./logwrite');
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, __dirname);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'aasasa-' + Date.now());
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

router.post("/upload", function(req,res){
  // res.send(" we got it !!")
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
    else{
      res.end("File is uploaded" + __dirname);
    }

    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Which HTTP verb are you using? And can you please post your `web.config` file?

Comment: @AaronChen I'm using POST HTTP verb and I have updated question  with web.config file

Comment: Your `web.config` looks fine. Does the node.js app work locally?

Comment: @AaronChen The node.js app is hosted on Azure web app.